# How can I stop my mouse double-clicking when I only click once?

Tags: mouse

Mostly a single click will act like two clicks.

For example: I want to go back one page on a web-browser but go back two
or I have word processor open and want to open the drop down menu to change fonts and it opens and closes in one stroke as though I had double-clicked.

It makes things extra tedious and laborious as one can imagine having to try again each time V E R Y carefully

I have already checked the Mouse speed specification under Systems and brought that right down but no change.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried another mouse? It sounds like a broken or worn mouse.

Comment: Hadn't considered that possibility. Its worked fine on other distros incl. windows but I guess its possible. Unfortunately, don't have another mouse handy, otherwise I could test that. Thx.

Comment: double-clicking is a feature only in "Files", the rest of the system doesn't have any double-clicking feature... So I vote for a broken mouse as well

Answer (score 7):

You can test to see if your mouse is broken by running the following in terminal:

```
xev | grep ButtonRelease
```

You'll see a white box with a black square in it. Click the square. Each time you click you will see a line in your terminal window. Ensure that your mouse is only clicking once.